# com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not deserialize to type class javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, json, web-services, maven, jersey

I have Jersey 1.19 REST web service which return custom @XmlRootElement response objects and works well. However, when I execute tests which should assert javax.ws.rs.core.Response later, I get exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not deserialize to type class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
    at com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter.readFrom(GensonJsonConverter.java:127)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634)
```

Response type:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyResponse {
    public String message;
}
```

Endpoint which returns MyResponse:

```
@GET
@Path("/info")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MyResponse getInfo(){
    return new MyResponse();
}
```

My pom.xml fragments containing related libraries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
    <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you are supposed to deserialize to your target pojo type not javax.ws.rs.core.Response. You should post the code you use.

Comment: Updated. It works well when I deserialize my custom - specific type MyResponse but I suppose that it should wrapped with javax.ws.rs.core.Response. When I tested with Jersey 2, it wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the problem on the client side. Changed expected type from Response to com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse:

```
protected ClientResponse executeGet(String path){
    WebResource resource = resource().path(path);
    Builder builder = resource.header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    return builder.get(ClientResponse.class);
}
```